# SQL query for 2 tables

Tags: sql, select

There are 2 SQL tables:

```
Table1
    ID | field1
    1  | a
    2  | b

Table2
        field1 | field2
        a      | 111
        a      | 222
        b      | 333
        b      | 444
        b      | 555
```

I need to get the following `Table3`:

```
ID | field1 | field2
1  | a      | 111
1  | a      | 222
2  | b      | 333
2  | b      | 444
2  | b      | 555
```

I tired to run such SQL query:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.field1, t2.field2 FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.field1=t2.field1;
```

but as a result I received duplicated entries, sth like this

```
ID | field1 | field2
1  | a      | 111
1  | a      | 111
2  | a      | 222
2  | a      | 222
```

etc.

Please help.

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT works fine as suggested below. I don't know why these answers have been downvoted. Looks like someone is not in a good mood:)

Comment: So does GROUP BY : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76afc/3

Comment: @KlausosKlausos: I didn't downvote but I think the downvotes are fair. It's like going to the doctor and saying "It hurts when I touch my stomach here" and your doctor replies "Then don't touch your stomach" and sends you home. The pain goes away but it doesn't really address the fundamental problem. You need to cure the cause, not hide the symptoms. You will likely get more serious problems in the future  if you don't deal with it now, especially if you later try to do things like SUM where the DISTINCT trick won't work.

Comment: @MarkByers - You are making some assumptions that may not be correct: a) That the user can modify the data, b) that the user can modify the schema, c) that the schema is actually incorrect, and even *should* or *can* be modified. I contend all of those assumptions are in question, so it is premature to say that only the answer based on those assumptions is correct and that the others should be downvoted.

Comment: @RedFilter: For what it's worth, I haven't downvoted any answers on this post, so please don't take it personally. I just feel that the OP didn't get a complete answer and the answers posted here (at the time I posted) acted like this is normal behaviour and that adding a DISTINCT is what any database professional would do in this situation, and that no alarm bells should be ringing. I think he needed a second diagnosis and that's why I posted my answer.

Comment: I agree with @Mark on this. @RedFilter you are making the opposite assumptions. I feel that if you had added those assumptions in your answer, you wouldn't had been dowvoted in the first place. 4 answers, all suggesting `DISTINCT` in a seemingly blind way, without any other advice or consideration, is probably the cause of the downvotes.

Comment: @ypercube The only assumption I made is that there was duplicate data and the sample data provided was incorrect. My assumptions turned out to be right. What I take issue with are categorical statements that DISTINCT should not be used and the schema must be changed. Mark's answer on its own is a good one. The subsequent comments, howver, go to far IMO.

Comment: @Mark no worries, I am not taking any personal issue with this. I will continue to have the greatest respect for the answers you provide on SO. Your answer provided an alternate approach to mine (and others) that I think is prefectly valid, and I would likely take that approach myself. My point is that telling someone to go and modify their data and schema when they do not understand basic SQL, and without knowing the business context of the situation (timelines, dependencies, data ownerhip, etc.), is not *neceesarily* the wisest approach.

Comment: I agree that there was duplicate data and the sample data provided was incorrect. If there are no other (not shown) columns in `Table1`, that means that there are duplicate rows in that "table". So, either the design is wrong or data should be corrected. Mark's advice "Remove the duplicate rows from the table" is the wisest in my opinion. Your answer is not wrong - and solves the issue, although in a temporary manner.

Comment: I'm voting to delete this entire question and all answers. It's clear that the OP isn't interested in participating in this discussion to clarify what his actual situation is. Just arguing amongst ourselves is a waste of time since none of us know more than what the OP wrote (which is basically nothing). It doesn't make this site a better place to continue this discussion. It also won't help the OP who is probably long gone by now, apparently happy with the DISTINCT "solution".

Answer (score 3):

(I am assuming your sample data is not representative of your issue, since it will result in no duplicates.)

You can use the `DISTINCT` keyword to eliminate duplicates, like this:

```
select distinct t1.ID,
    t1.field1,
    t2.field2
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.field1 = t2.field1;
```

Sample SQL Fiddle to illustrate the problem here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed198/1

Solution illustrated here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed198/2

Comment: Why would you need DISTINCT here?

Comment: @zmbq Because `DISTINCT` eliminates duplicate rows, which is the problem the OP is having.

Comment: @RedFilter I don't understand why all of them were downvoted.

Comment: Because some child opened this thread:))

Comment: I know what 'DISTINCT' does, I just don't understand why it's necessary in this case. Why would that JOIN result in duplicate rows?

Comment: @zmbq - I think you are making an assumption that the sample data provided is correct to indicate the problem. That is often not the case on SO :) I am taking the OP at their word when they say they are getting duplicate rows, and assuming they have not given good sample data.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach (although your SQL is ugly and hard to read) should work.

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76afc/1)

Your problem is that there are duplicates in one of your input tables. Try `SELECT * FROM Table1` or `SELECT * FROM Table2`and you'll probably see something like this:

```
ID | field1
1  | a
2  | b
1  | a
2  | b
```

I suggest:

- Removing the duplicate rows from the table.
- Adding a unique index on your `ID` field to prevent it happening again.

Comment: Yes, that *would* explain why DISTINCT is required. OP's example doesn't require DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` to remove duplicates from your result.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.field1, t2.field2
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.field1=t2.field1
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.field1, t2.field2;
```

Comment: Even if we agree that the "DISTINCT" approach is the correct answer to this question (I'm not sure it is, but let's just say it is for sake of argument), using GROUP BY to achieve it instead of just using DISTINCT is not a good approach IMHO. I didn't downvote this answer, but there's no reason to upvote it when better answers have been posted.

Comment: @MarkByers I don't base my votes on your opinion, but rather, mine, which is: this is a valid, correct answer that was needlessly voted down. I voted it up to compensate for the downvote it received.

Answer (score 0):

try using `DISTINCT` to get your results, also I would advise using JOIN syntax for your tables and not commas between the table names.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.field1, t2.field2 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t1.field1=t2.field1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to throw a SELECT DISTINCT at the front of that query.
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.field1, t2.field2 FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.field1=t2.field1;

Comment: I don't know why your answer is downvoted, but it does the right job for me.